# Select Row That do not have a Relation in Another Table

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm developing a game that a `User` can `Answer` some `Questions`.
I'm trying to created a controller action to return one `Question` that `User` not answered yet (A `Question` that do not have any `Answer` related with logged `User`).

My code attempt is not working properly.

- I found about mysql command `WHERE NOT EXISTS` and I think it can do that, but I do not know how to use it in `Yii Framework`.

---

Database:

[image]

---

Controller Action: (Not working properly)

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with=array('answers'=>array('condition'=>'user_id='.Yii::app()->user->id));
$criteria->having='count(answers.id)=0';
$model=Question::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found how to do searching at `Yii Documentation`.

---

Code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM question WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM answer WHERE answer.user_id='.Yii::app()->user->id.' AND answer.question_id=question.id);';
$question = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->queryRow();
```

---

Info:

`setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` is used to return the `data` as an `object`, so can access it like `$question->id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DAO with Yii, that is the most direct way to interact with databases.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao